# Python Selenium send_key object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to send keys on search bar from a column in a excel, it works fine previously but now it just return errors: object of type 'float' has no len().

Please find the code:

```
def search(key):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchCode"]').clear()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchCode"]').send_keys(key)
def get_keyword():
    data = pd.read_excel('search.xlsx')
    for d in data['code']:
        search(d)
```

If I change to:

```
def search(key):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchCode"]').clear()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchCode"]').send_keys(str(key))
def get_keyword():
    data = pd.read_excel('search.xlsx')
    for d in data['code']:
        search(d)
```

Then the search bar appears:  175717.0, but in excel, it is only 175717 and test format, it is a bit confusing...

Excel:(pretty sure no float value, and I convert to text format already

```
code
175717
175740
```

Could someone please help with this, thanks!

Comment: Could you post more of your code, like what you have implemented under `search` ?

Comment: Hi, I have add codes to search function, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to Selenium [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=send_keys#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys)

```
send_keys(*value)[source]
    Simulates typing into the element.
    Args :  
        value - A string for typing, or setting form fields. For setting file inputs, this could be a local file path.
```

`send_keys` accepts a `str` not a `float`
So in your case you'd be replacing `d` with `str(d)`
The error occurred because [len](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)
returns the number of items in an object, which is not valid for a `float`.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but when it converted to str, 175717.0 appears, not sure why as in excel ,it is a integer.

Comment: According to your error it seems that you end up with a float when you iterate through elements under data['code'], you can convert it to `int` first then cast it to a string